# convert all the elements in a string to list of string items, if string contains any digit greater than 5 and space remove it and return a list

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
input = "my string 58"
output = ['m','y','s','t','r','i','n','g','5']
```

No spaces no digit greater than 5 in the output.

```
string1 = "my string 58"
for x in string1:
    print(list(x),end='')
    for y in x:
        if y.isdigit():
            print(int(y))
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
output=[]
inpt = "my string 58"
for x in inpt:
    if x==' ' or (x.isdigit() and int(x)>5):
        continue
    else:
        output.append(x)

#['m', 'y', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '5']
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.